# Validation not stopping data and function keeps on inserting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

I just have a quick question:

In the below function I would like `if the username is taken return the error return false but if it doesn't exist return true and continue`  I dont think I have my T/F in the correct order.

```
public function username_check($username)
    {
        if($username == TRUE)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check','Sorry the username %s is already taken!');
            return true;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I have got toms code working ok but I now have a issue with it seems the callback is not working and it just keeps on adding the user to the database even through it already exists!

**View:**

```
<h1><?php echo $companyName; echo nbs(1);?> - <?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>



<?php
if($success == TRUE) {
echo '<section id = "validation">Page Updated</section>';   
}
?>
    <p>Error: <?php echo validation_errors();?></p>
    <div class="formContent">
        <form action="createUser" method="post">
            <fieldset class="control-group">
                <label for="userName">User Name:</label><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"  value="<?php echo set_value('userName'); ?>" placeholder="User Name">
                <label for="userPassword">User Password:</label><input type="password" id="userPassword" name="userPassword" placeholder="User Password">
                <label for="userFirstName">First Name:</label><input type="text" id="userFirstName" name="userFirstName" value="<?php echo set_value('userFirstName'); ?>" placeholder="First Name">
                <label for="userLastName">Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="userLastName" name="userLastName" value="<?php echo set_value('userLastName'); ?>" placeholder="Last Name">
                <label for="userEmail">E-Mail:</label> <input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail"  value="<?php echo set_value('userEmail'); ?>" placeholder="Admin E-mail">
                <label for="userGroup"> User Group:</label>
                    <select name="userGroup" id="userGroup">
                        <option value="select"<?=(set_value('userGroup')=='select')?' selected="selected" ':''?>>Please Select</option>
                        <option value="admin" <?=(set_value('userGroup')=='admin')?' selected="selected" ':''?>>Admin</option>
                        <option value="user" <?=(set_value('userGroup')=='user')?' selected="selected" ':''?>>User</option>
                    </select>
                <label for="userActive"> User Active:</label>
                        <select name="userActive" id="userActive">
                            <option value="select" <?=(set_value('userActive')=='select')?' selected="selected" ':''?>>Please Select</option>
                            <option value="yes" <?=(set_value('userActive')=='yes')?' selected="selected" ':''?>>Yes</option>
                            <option value="no" <?=(set_value('userActive')=='no')?' selected="selected" ':''?>>No</option>
                        </select>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
    {
        //Form Validation prep making sure its all clean

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userName', 'User Name', 'trim|required|callback_username_check|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPassword', 'User Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|sha1');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userFirstName', 'First Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userLastName', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userEmail', 'E-Mail', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userGroup', 'User Group', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userActive', 'User Active', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        //If form validation fails load previous page with errors else do the job and insert data into db

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['success'] = "";
        }else{
            $username = $this->input->post('userName');
            $password = $this->input->post('userPassword');
            $firstname = $this->input->post('userFirstName');
            $lastname = $this->input->post('userLastName');
            $email = $this->input->post('userEmail');
            $group = $this->input->post('userGroup');
            $active = $this->input->post('userActive');

            $passwordHash = $this->encrypt->sha1($password); // Lets encrypt the password why sha1?  MD5 is for tossers

            // If the data is correct follow through with db insert

            if($this->users_model->createUser($username,$passwordHash,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$group,$active))
            {
                $data['success'] = TRUE;

            }

        }
        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyName();
        $data['pageTitle'] = "Create User";
        $this->load->view('admin/assets/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/createUser', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/assets/footer');
    }

    public function username_check($username)
    {
        if($this->users_model->username_taken($username))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'Sorry the username %s is taken!');
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
function createUser($username = NULL ,$passwordHash = NULL ,$firstname = NULL ,$lastname = NULL ,$email = NULL,$group = NULL ,$active = NULL)
{
    $data = array('userName' => $username, 'userFirstName' => $firstname, 'userLastName' => $lastname, 'userEmail' => $email, 'userPassword' => sha1($passwordHash), 'userGroup' => $group, 'userActive' => $active);

$this->db->insert('users',$data);

return TRUE;
}

function username_taken($username)
{
    $this->db->select('userName');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('userName', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: In your `if` are you meaning to check that the variable `$username` has been passed to the function? Or whether the `$username` is *equal to* `TRUE`? Because what you're actually checking is the latter.

Comment: `return true and continue` ? you can't really do that, can you? I mean return from a function and than proceed within that function...

Comment: Now you're checking whether `$username` is set to `true`. I'm guessing what you want to do is ask your database whether the username exists. Also, this looks like a callback for CodeIgniter. If that's the case, you should name your function `_username_check` to make it inaccessible through a GET request.

Comment: pretty sure you can jus get away with saying if ($username) afaik a variable evaluates to true if it is set no need for comparisons

Comment: You may want to look at the [=== operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) since it makes comparisons more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're getting now is because you use both `get('users')` and `from('users')`. You should be using either:

```
 $this->db->select('userName');
 $this->db->from('users');
 $this->db->where('userName', $username);
 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Or:

```
 $this->db->select('userName');
 $this->db->where('userName', $username);
 $query = $this->db->get('users');
```

Update: to get it to work your code should look like this:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('userName', 'User Name', 'trim|required|callback_username_check|xss_clean');

  // Etc
}

public function username_check($username)
{
  if($this->users_model->username_taken($username))
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'Sorry the username %s is taken!');
    return FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Model:

```
function username_taken($username)
{
  $this->db->where('userName', $username);
  return $this->db->count_all_results('users') > 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I am really confused now see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288142/controller-form-doing-strange-things-when-content-is-implemented

Comment: Hm, so `is_unique` doesn't work? Your code in the other question looks OK, so I don't know what's going on there. In that case stick to Tom's answer and update the `username_taken` function in your model with what I'm suggesting above.

Comment: Hey,  I have just tried your first query and got  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given.  The latter query gave the above error.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_num_rows`, but CodeIgniter's built-in function: `if($query->num_rows() > 0)`. If you are using CodeIgniter's Active Record, you shouldn't use any of the `mysql_*` functions. Always look for a built-in function.

Comment: Hey,  thanks for that but I am still not getting any errors and it just keeps on adding an admin user to the db

Comment: You have to return `FALSE` from `username_check` if the username is already taken. Not `TRUE`!

Comment: No!! You should ONLY change it in the controller... I will update my answer to make it clear exactly what the code should look like.